# **tokens when tokens is a dictionary

Tags: python, nlp, bert

Trying to understand the code from https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/measuring-text-similarity-using-bert/

I am looking at understanding the syntax on these two lines:

```
token['input_ids'] = torch.stack(token['input_ids'])
token['attention_mask'] = torch.stack(token['attention_mask'])
```

```
output = model(**token)
output.keys()
```

What does `**tokens` do? I can't seem to print it, or debug its value. I get a `Syntax Error` exception

I am familiar with the role of `**arg` in function calls, where it changes an expression like (a=1, b=2) to a dictionary like `{'a':1, 'b':2}`, but what does it do when the expression is already a dictionary? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2):

When **dict is used in a function call like that, the dictionary is expanded into keyword arguments, so the dictionary keys become the keywords and the dictionary values become the argument values. So in your case:

```
output = model(**token)
```

is expanded to:

```
output = model(input_ids=token['input_ids'], attention_mask=token['attention_mask'])
```